# zsh vcs_info - no hooks or debug output

Tags: git, version-control, zsh

I'm trying to add vcs_info hooks to my .zshrc but not even the debug option yields output and I haven't been able to figure out why - any hints?
**Sources:**
[vcs_info examples](http://zsh.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=zsh/zsh;a=blob_plain;f=Misc/vcs_info-examples)
[shouse .zsh prompt](http://github.com/whiteinge/dotfiles/blob/master/.zsh_shouse_prompt)
**Excerpt from my .zshrc:**

```
setopt prompt_subst
autoload -Uz vcs_info

zstyle ':vcs_info:*+*:*' debug true
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' enable git
zstyle ':vcs_info:git*:*' get-revision true
zstyle ':vcs_info:git*:*' check-for-changes true
zstyle ':vcs_info:git*' formats '%b'
zstyle ':vcs_info:git*' actionformats '%b:%a'
zstyle ':vcs_info:git*+set-message:*' hooks foobar

function +vi-foobar() { echo "foobar" }
function prompt_precmd() { vcs_info }
function set_prompt { PROMPT="${vcs_info_msg_0_}" }

autoload -U add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd prompt_precmd
add-zsh-hook precmd set_prompt
```

Comment: The entire .zshrc is available at my GitHub page (subject to change), I hope I didn't leave out anything crucial in the excerpt. OS X 10.6.8, zsh 4.3.9 (i386-apple-darwin10.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is fine but hooks (and the debug feature?) were added to vcs_info in zsh 4.3.11 or 4.3.12. Problem is resolved by updating zsh to one of these or later versions.

Pardon the non-existing link to the entire .zshrc, didn't realize links get stripped out of comments.